# Using Swift, I seem to get this error ONLY SOMETIMES when using arc4random. Why, and how do I fix it?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm getting this error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Most of the time (not all) when I'm using `arc4random()` in Xcode 6 with Swift.  I didn't ever get this error in Xcode 5 in Objective C. Curiously, if I use `arc4random_uniform()`, I don't run into this problem.

How do I use `arc4random()` without getting this error?

Comment: Remember it's still in beta. It might very well be a bug. Try to reproduce the problem in the very smallest piece you can and report it.

Comment: Restarting XCode 6 solved the problem for me when I faced the same issue. Looks like a bug.

Comment: I thing it's simply an undefined behaviour in Apples internal code. You might solve this, by calling the C equivalent.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried restarting a few times and it didn't seem to change anything for me.

Comment: This same error is happening for me also. Nothing wrong on my part, just a bug on Apples.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in `arc4random`?  In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089631/how-to-pull-random-item-out-of-an-array-in-swift/24091085?noredirect=1#comment37157292_24091085) the problem was actually an out of bounds array index caused by `arc4random` returning negative numbers (which would be fixed with `arc4random_uniform`)

Comment: The other possibility is that `arc4random` returns a `UInt32`, that means that half the time it's going to overflow an `Int32` if you try to assign by casting, since swift protects against overflows, that could cause crashes as well.  `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` is usually just an `abort()` call.  Continue and check the log for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it:

```
var _shiom = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayshiftingTile.count)))
```

Comment: Please explain what is worng with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.

Comment: func arc4random() -> UInt32 only return type but func arc4random_uniform(_: UInt32) -> UInt32 , Value set and return type