# How to pull random item out of an array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I'm trying to pull a random item out of an array. When I run, it works about 50/50 between pulling a random item and giving me this error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION". Any idea what's going on?

Right now my code looks like this: **BEFORE Solution**

```
   func randomCard() -> Card {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random()) % cardArray.count
    let randomCard = cardArray[randomIndex]

    cardArray.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)

    return randomCard
}
```

**After**

```
   func randomCard() -> Card {

    let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardArray.count))
    let randomCard = cardArray[randomIndex.hashValue]

    cardArray.removeAtIndex(randomIndex.hashValue)

    return randomCard
}
```

This is what I'm using now and seems to be working.Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Are you able to determine which values of `randomIndex` work, and which ones return `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`?

Comment: Just seems to be random. It works sometimes and other times it doesn't.

Comment: Which line caused the error? Log randomIndex.

Comment: @JustinCabral To start troubleshooting, I would record the exact 'bad' values and see if you can reproduce it by manually feeding those bad values into `cardArray.removeAtIndex(`

Comment: BTW, It is better (no bias) and easier to use arc4random_uniform(cardArray.count);

Comment: is it the removal or what happens with the randomCard after it is removed from the array?

Comment: The bad instruction comes on the return. @Zaph i'll use that from now on, def looks cleaner.

Comment: This sounds like [the same bug someone experienced a couple of days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044316/using-swift-i-seem-to-get-this-error-only-sometimes-when-using-arc4random-why). You're not doing anything wrong — it's a bug in Swift, which is after all still in beta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arc4random` can return negative numbers which would cause you problems since `negative % positive = negative`  A better approach would be to use `arc4random_uniform`

```
let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardArray.count))
```

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION seems like a bad exception to throw on a bounds error, but that does seem to be what you get.

Comment: When I try to use arc4random_uniform(cardArray.count) I get an error saying that NSNumber cannont be sent to UInt32.